# Get rows by transitivity in mysql

Tags: mysql, transitivity

Suppose i have the following table:

```
Images

|id | similarTo|
|---|----------|
|1  |  2       |
|2  |  3       |
|--------------|
```

Where similarTo is a foriegn key to id.  What i want is a query that can fetch the transitive closure of an id down to 2 levels both ways.  In other words, what we have is:  A --> B ---> C
and also  C --> B --> A

And so in this case i would like it to return:

```
Given 1: 2,3
Given 2: 1,3
Given 3: 1,2
```

Essentially i am storing the function (Image A) similarTo(Image B) in a table. This function goes both ways, so if A is similar to B, then B is similar to A. Now i need a query that can find all images similar to a given image by up to two levels/steps... (that is if given A --> B --> C --> D, now if i want to find all images similar to A, it would return B,C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be a query like below:

```
SELECT 
id,
similarTo
From images

UNION ALL

SELECT 
t1.id,
t2.similarTo
FROM images t1
INNER JOIN images t2 ON t1.similarTo = t2.id AND t1.id < t2.id
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2fbcf4/1/0)</kbd>

The second query actually begets the `transitive` relation. And the first one gets all the defined relationships in your table.

**Output:**

You will get output like below:

```
| id | similarTo |
|----|-----------|
|  1 |         2 |
|  2 |         3 |
|  1 |         3 |
```

**EDIT:**

For specific `id` say `id=2`:

```
SELECT 
id,
similarTo
From images
WHERE id=2 or similarTo=2

UNION ALL

SELECT 
t1.id,
t2.similarTo
FROM images t1
INNER JOIN images t2 ON t1.similarTo=2 AND t2.id =2 AND t1.id < t2.id
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2fbcf4/14/0)</kbd>

Comment: Great, how would i query for a specific id, say 2? (so that it returns ex. 1,3)